# concatenate strings with atomic update in peewee using sqlite db

Tags: sqlite, peewee

I would like to update a text field in an sqlite database created using the peewee python library. Specifically I would like to use peewee's atomic updates something like:

```
query = Table.update(textfield = Table.textfield + 'string').where(some condition)

query.execute()
```

This type of update works fine for numeric fields but not for text fields.  I'm guessing there may be a way to do this with the sqlite || operator, but as sql in general is somewhat new to me I am unable to figure it out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [concat](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/querying.html#query-operators) operator:

```
query = Table.update(textfield=Table.textfield.concat('string')).where(whatever)
query.execute()
```

The `concat` operator will use `||` under-the-hood.

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly.  One follow up question.  How would I handle a null field.  I found a reference to COALESCE in a different stack overflow thread, but I'm not sure how to add it in here.